# after payment is successful i want to navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

i'm working on a app. after payment is successful i want to navigate to another page.

Here is the code of my app payment method  in the

```
void handlerPaymentSuccess() {    Navigator.push(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Itemsbuy()));
```

i coded this to navigate that page but after payment is success this is not showing,
but after payment done its showing only payment successful from the razorpay but its not showing my page which i navigated. after payment success it is redirecting to the second route not redirecting to the Itemsbuy();

```
 class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {


 @override


_SecondRouteState createState() => _SecondRouteState();}



class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {



 Razorpay razorpay;



TextEditingController textEditingController = new TextEditingController();



@override



void initState() {


 razorpay = new Razorpay();

razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_SUCCESS, handlerPaymentSuccess);
razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_PAYMENT_ERROR, handlerPaymentError);
razorpay.on(Razorpay.EVENT_EXTERNAL_WALLET, handlerExternalWallet);

super.initState(); }



void handlerPaymentSuccess() {
 Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Itemsbuy()));//Items purchased}
```

this is the navigation that i want to push

```
void handlerPaymentError() 
{
print('error'); }




void handlerExternalWallet() 


  @override



void dispose() 

{
super.dispose();

razorpay.clear(); }






var options = {


"key": "empty",


 "amount": empty,


 "name": 'empty',


"Description": 'empty',
};
try {

  razorpay.open(options);

} catch (e) {

  debugPrint('error');

}}
```

thank you

Comment: You should really start formatting your code better. It will be horrible to read later on if you continue like that...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get) package for navigation instead of Navigator.of(context)

Example:

```
void handlerPaymentSuccess() {
     Get.to(Itemsbuy());
}
```

Also make sure to use **GetMaterialApp** instead of **MaterialApp** like this:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      home: SplashScreen(),
      color: violet,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
      ).copyWith(textTheme: GoogleFonts.montserratTextTheme()),
    );
  }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: No its Not Working . An d when i Rouute other page it showing black screen

Comment: its not working and can you please help me in other way

Comment: after payment done its showing only payment successful from the razorpay but its not showing mt page which i navigated and after payment success it is redirecting to the second route

Answer (score 0):

class _Payment extends State {
bool paymentDone = false;

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
if (paymentDone == true) {
    return NewPage();
}
else{
    return CurrentPage(); 
}
}
void _handlePaymentSuccess(PaymentSuccessResponse response) async {
Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "SUCCESS: " + response.paymentId, timeInSecForIosWeb: 4);
setState(() {
    paymentDone = true;
);}
}
```

}

Comment: can you please write the code clearly i didnt undert where the class payment comes from

Comment: I am having stateful widget as Payment
You can write anything

Comment: so in the stateful widget i have to give bool value am i right ????